# Whats is the netcat command to open multiple ports to a mail server

Tags: netcat

What is the netcat command to open a multiple new connections to mail.server.net on port 25, 80 & 110.
I need a single command to open up multiple ports ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with nc. What you can actually do is write a shell script for achieving the same. If you express your intentions clearly then there may be some other way of doing it.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, anyhow this is what i need "Enter the command which needs to be entered to open a multiple new connections to mail.server.net on port 25, 80 & 110." that's the question that was raised so is there any ways to achieve it or is there any other ways if so please let me know